# Importing a script with parsing arguments in python

Tags: python, function, parsing, spyder

Support that I have a script with parsing arguments named `my_function.py`. This script has two arguments (`--name` and `--time`). In a normal case, we can use this script directly like `my_function --name X1 --time 23`. How can I import this script (`import my_function as mf)` to my python script and use it there?

Comment: Right now this question is a bit too theoretical. Can you provide some implementation details? Sounds like you're just importing a module that normally you execute from the command line

Comment: `my_function.py` is a Python script, not a function. This script should contain a function that does the important job, independently from the arguments parsing.

Comment: @C.Nivs yes. That's exactly the case. I think there should be a proper way to import this function and later call it with parsing arguments in a script.

Comment: @Thierry Lathuille Even for that specific function, I need to pass some arguments to it (the parsing ones). So I need to use again `parse_args` function inside of `my_function` for specifying those arguments. My question here is for finding a straightforward and cleaner way to do this.

Comment: Again, `my_function.py` is **not** a function; If run as the main script, it should parse the arguments from the command line and pass them to a function that it contains that does what has to be done. If used as a module, you just call this function with the right arguments.